# Migrating Metadata Storage from SQL Server to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, sql-server, metadata, migration

Currently we have somewhere around 2500 metadata records in a SQL Server table to relate to an online mapping tool. I am trying to formulate some sort of idea of how I can take all those records out and import them into the metadata standard using ArcGIS Online.

Ideally, this would be solved by extracting the SQL Server table records as an XML for each record, and then rename or map the SQL Server fields to the applicable AGS Online metadata fields. Lastly, the new XML would be imported somehow into AGS Online, populating the relevant fields defined before.

Since there's a lot of records, I would like to automate at least part of this. Does anyone have a medium or high level idea of how this could happen?